# How to prevent recalling my css animation after using ':active' selector?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I would like to add a bouncing animation to my button. Button should enter the screen with this animation. It works. But after that I added an :active selector.

```
#button:active{
 transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

And I doesn't work. It just ignores this selector. But I figured out that after adding an animation name to this selector it works. Only then but the problem is that it repeats my bouncing animation as well. It can be any name. Even a name of an animation which doesn't exist. For example:

```
#button:active{
 transform: translateX(20px);
 animation-name: not_existing_animation;
}
```

And that's why I need help. I made a fiddle to let you better see my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/gfd2pjbz/3/

Comment: You need this animation on every click?

Comment: Yes I need it on every click

Comment: You mean this move to the right (translateY)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gfd2pjbz/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution about this **animation** issue. I don't know is it work for you. But I found few `coding` issue in your **[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfd2pjbz/3/)**.

**First codding issue.**

You haven't flow the **W3C** rules. `button` is a closing `tag` element. It's not none closing `tag` element like `<img />` `<br />` etc.

**Second codding issue.**

You have to forgot to write `position` direction `CSS` property. `position: fixed | absolute | sticky` need to set `left | right | top | bottom` direction.

I tested your fiddle many times why not `:active` `pseudo-class` not work after `clicked`. Problem found from your first `animation`. `animation` and `bounceInDown` `classes` are contain the `transform` property. Your `animation` will not work until you remove the `animation` and `bunceInDown` `classes`. So I need to write a `function` for remove those `classes`.

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('animated bounceInDown');
    });
});
```

When I removed those `classes` I seen button is disappeared because of `#button`  `opacity:` is `0;`. So I need `opacity: 1;` in `#button`.

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('opacity-visible');
    });
});
```

Now found an another issue. Issue is first `click` `:active` `animation` not working. Because of the first `click` didn't allow `transform` property until `animation` `classes` are removed. Then need add a `class` when removing those `animation` `classes`. After added new `class` the `:active` `animation` will work.

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Now need to set a `timeOut` `function` for remove the `active` `class` for `button` back to original place for next `clicked` `animation`. Now I can write all `function` together.

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active opacity-visible');
    $(this).removeClass('animated bounceInDown');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#button').removeClass('active');
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

Checked the snipped. I hope it will help you to perform the best solution.

```js
setTimeout( function(){
$("#button").addClass("animated bounceInDown");
}, 1000);

$(function(){
 $('#button').on('click', function(){
   $(this).addClass('active opacity-visible');
    $(this).removeClass('animated bounceInDown');
    setTimeout(function(){
     $('#button').removeClass('active');
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
*:focus{
    outline: none !important;
}
*{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
#button {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

#button:active{
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(50%) !important;
 /* animation-name: not_existing_animation; */
}
#button.opacity-visible{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#button.active{
  background-color: black;
  transform: translateX(50%) !important;
}

/*!
 * animate.css -http://daneden.me/animate
 * Version - 3.5.2
 * Licensed under the MIT license - http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2017 Daniel Eden
 */

.bounceInDown {
  animation-name: bounceInDown;
  opacity: 1!important;
}


.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes bounceInDown {
  from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }

  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }

  to {
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

I suggest you to don't write `:active` `css` for this type of `animation`. More specification here on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active).

Answer (score 2):

I found a super cool solution for you.

**First see the preview:** https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/aVjGMY

Separate initial `opacity` to a class and add this class to your button.

**Like:**

```
<button id="button" class="visibility"/>
```

**And CSS:**

```
.visibility {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Now remove the animation and your desire transform when button is `:active` by this code:

```
#button:active {
  transform: translate3d(20px, 0, 0);
  /* transform: translateX(20px); you can also use this */
  animation-name: none; 
}
```

It will now translate to right, but bouncing still remain. To remove this bouncing do this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#button", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("animated bounceInDown visibility");
});
```

It will remove animation that you added when first load or initialize.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Promise` to just remove the **bouncing** class. Check also the minor css modifications in the snippet below.

```js
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var $timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("button").classList.add("animated", "bounceInDown");
  }, 1000);
  if ($timeout) {
    resolve($timeout);
  } else {
    reject('Failure!');
  }
});
p.then(function(response) {
  if (response) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("button").classList.remove("bounceInDown");
      console.log("Yay! finished");
    }, 1900);
  }

}).catch(function() {
  console.log("Something went wrong");
});
```

```css
#button {
  position: fixed;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  opacity: 0;
}

button.animated:active,
button.animated:focus {
  transform: translateX(20px);
  background-color: red;
}

.bounceInDown {
  animation-name: bounceInDown;
  opacity: 1!important;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.animated {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 1!important;
  transition: transform 2s, background-color 1s;
}

@keyframes bounceInDown {
  from,
  60%,
  75%,
  90%,
  to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button" />
```